# App permissions for updating events with graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want my app to be able to edit all events for which user is admin. It appears that the app can only update events that were created by the app. I've tested this a few different ways and it always comes the same. It returns error 200, permissions error.

Is this by design or is it a bug? Is there anyway to grant permission to the app to allow updating events not created by the app?

Events that were initially created by the app can be updated by the app.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be by design. The app must be designated as admin of the event. It can only be assigned as admin if the app creates the event. There is no way to find all admins of an event, either.